# Get CSS property of element in transition / Pause CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to pause a css3 transition, so the element in question maintains it's exact css properties when a pause button is clicked. The way I think about going about is getting the CSS properties of the element during the transition and setting them to that with .css(), would this work? How would I get the CSS properties of the element during the transition.

HTML

```
 <div id="productimage">        
   </div>
<a href="#" id="pause">Pause</a>
```

CSS

```
    #productimage {
        position:absolute;
        height: 550px;
        width: 393px;
        background-image: url("../img/blusen.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:50% 50%;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-size:396px 600px;
        top:191px;
        left:10px;
    }


#productimage.step1 {
    background-size:1500px 2275px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$("#pause").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        $('#productimage').addClass('step1');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pause a transition by copying the attributes changed by the transition, setting the attributes to those changed attributes, and then removing the class that animates it. Of course if you are using the same object to animate/pause you will need to animate the first click then pause it the next click.

**Note:** the `!important` in the CSS `background-size` attribute is necessary unless you have a more leveled selector for the animation class than the jQuery selector, aka something like `div #productimage.step1 {` as opposed to just `#productimage.step1 {`. Since `#productimage` and `#productimage.step1` are both one level, your example requires the `!important`

I took this approach and came up with [**this example jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/NzHhd/1/)

```
/* jQuery */
var image = $("#productimage");
$("#pause").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!image.hasClass('step1'))
    {
        image.addClass('step1');
    }
    else {
        var css = image.css("background-size"); // Get the changed attribute(s)
        image.css({'background-size': css}); // Set the changed attribute(s)
        image.removeClass('step1');
    }
});

/* Changed CSS */
#productimage.step1 {
    -webkit-transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out;
    background-size:1500px 2275px !important;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using jQuery .stop?  You could also use a callback to skip to the end of the given event, such as animate().

Documentation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Also, have a look towards the bottom of the page, there is a working demonstration with onclick .stop events which I think applies well to your situation.

Comment: but that is when animating in jquery, I animate by adding a class to an element which has css3 transition.

Comment: @user1937021 Plus you want it to stop mid-transition, correct?

Comment: True, but why not use animate with transition? :p